# Agrupar o Contar valores repetidos SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql, join

Este query me trae la informacion correctamente con la diferencia que me trae los duplicados, entonces lo que quiero hacer es otra columna donde me diga cuantas veces se repite el mismo numero en este caso los repetidos esta aqui (E.N_PARTE) ejemplo de lo que devuelve

```
E.N_PARTE
AAA
AAA
BBB
CCC
BBB
```

Lo que quiero es agregar otra columna donde

```
Repetidos E.N_PARTE
   2      AAA
   2      BBB
   1      CCC


SELECT E.NOM_ALMACENISTA, E.N_PARTE, E.DESCRIPCION, E.INV_MINIMO, 
E.INV_MAXIMO, E.INV_EXISTE, E.COS_UNIDLLS,HT.FCH_REGISTRO
FROM ELENTRADAS AS E LEFT OUTER JOIN 
HISTORIAL AS HT ON HT.NUM_PART = E.N_PARTE 
WHERE (HT.FCH_REGISTRO BETWEEN '2018-08-24' AND '2018-08-24') AND (E.DEPART 
= 'Departamento1' )
order by HT.FCH_REGISTRO ASC
```

Gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Edita la pregunta para poder entenderte mejor lo que quieres @Manny

Comment: A ver si se entiende un poco mas...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que tienes que hacer es agrupar por el campo que quiere y luego contar ese campo y te dará la cantidad de registros repetidos de ese Campo

```
SELECT E.N_PARTE, COUNT(E.N_PARTE) AS REPETIDOS
FROM ELENTRADAS AS E LEFT OUTER JOIN 
HISTORIAL AS HT ON HT.NUM_PART = E.N_PARTE 
WHERE (HT.FCH_REGISTRO BETWEEN '2018-08-24' AND '2018-08-24') AND (E.DEPART = 'Departamento1' )
GROUP BY E.N_PARTE
order by HT.FCH_REGISTRO ASC
```

Comment: es lo que intente pero en el select tengo una campo que se carga de la otra(HISTORIAL) tabla entonces me genera conflicto.

Comment: Pero que te dice el conflicto

Comment: Gracias, si estaba funcionando, solo que no estaba agregando todos los campos del select al GROUP BY, los agregue y ahora si me da el resultado que estaba buscando.

Answer (score 4):

Tienes que añadir un group by al final como en el siguiente ejemplo

```
SELECT COUNT(E.*) as Repetidos, E.N_PARTE
FROM ELENTRADAS AS E 
GROUP BY E.N_PARTE
```

También tienes que tener en cuenta que lo argumentos que pongas en el select no generen conflicto con el group by.

Comment: genera conflicto tu ejemplo porque tengo un campo HT.FCH_REGISTRO que biene de la otra tabla HISTORIAL :(

Comment: Gracias, solo tenia que agregar los campos del select en la clausuala GROUP BY, saludos.

Comment: ok, si te fue útil marcala como correcta...